# How to use kubectl command for kubernetes implemented in rancher run with docker?

Tags: kubernetes, rancher

I built a rancher using docker on server 1.

I created and added a kubernetes cluster on server 2, and I wanted to access the kubernetes with the kubectl command on server 2 local, but localhost:8080 error is displayed.

How can I apply kubectl command to kubernetes configured with docker rancher locally?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed that issue modifying the kube config file.

The kubeconfig file can be checked by entering the rancher

The file to be modified is ~/.kube/config